# How to delete state by name for all keys

Tags: apache-flink, rocksdb

I had flowing state:

```
    public static final ValueStateDescriptor<String> MY_STATE_DESCRIPTOR =
            new ValueStateDescriptor<>("myState", String.class);

    static {
        MY_STATE_DESCRIPTOR.setQueryable("QueryableMyState");
    }

    protected transient ValueState<String> myState;

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) {
        myState = getRuntimeContext().getState(MY_STATE_DESCRIPTOR);
    }
```

in my `KeyedCoProcessFunction` implementation. But I don't need it any more and I cannot find how to delete all entries from that `"myState"` if I don't know all the keys in that state.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have other state in this application that you don't want to lose.

A few options:

(1) Use the State Processor API to modify a savepoint. Only carry over the state you want to keep. Or use the State Processor API to dump out a list of all of the keys for which there is state, and then use that knowledge to clear it. See [ReadRidesAndFaresSnapshot.java](https://github.com/ververica/flink-training/blob/master/state-processor/src/main/java/com/ververica/flink/training/exercises/ReadRidesAndFaresSnapshot.java) for an example showing how to use this API with state snapshots taken from [this application](https://github.com/ververica/flink-training/blob/master/rides-and-fares/src/solution/java/org/apache/flink/training/solutions/ridesandfares/RidesAndFaresSolution.java).

(2) Temporarily turn the `KeyedCoProcessFunction` into a `KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction` with the same UID, and use the `applyToKeyedState` method to loop over all the keys and clear the state. (This is a somewhat hacky solution which I'm including just for fun.)

(3) Throw away all of your state and start over.

Comment: Thank you. Second point is most useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

Can state TTL achieve the same effect? A time-to-live (TTL) can be assigned to the keyed state of any type. If a TTL is configured and a state value has expired, the stored value will be cleaned up on a best effort basis which is discussed in more detail below.